# Succinct way to create linestrings from each point in one df to all points in another df

Tags: r, sf

I have these two sf-dataframes:

### origins

5 points

```
structure(list(geometry = structure(list(structure(c(16.3092476330243, 
48.1219365079274), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(16.4084397163495, 
48.1219365079274), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(16.4155248651584, 
48.1219365079274), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(16.4296951627763, 
48.1219365079274), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(16.224225847317, 
48.1290216567363), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 16.224225847317, 
ymin = 48.1219365079274, xmax = 16.4296951627763, ymax = 48.1290216567363
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "WGS 84", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(integer(0), levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor", names = character(0)), class = c("sf", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

### destinations

3 points

```
structure(list(name = structure(c("dest_1", "dest_2", "dest_3"
), class = c("glue", "character")), geometry = structure(list(
    structure(c(16.44011, 48.21178), class = c("XY", "POINT", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(16.424198595501, 48.2380217752047), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(16.4110495494276, 48.2291189117279
    ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, precision = 0, crs = structure(list(
    input = "EPSG:4326", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    ENSEMBLE[\"World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble\",\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)\"],\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), bbox = structure(c(xmin = 16.4110495494276, 
ymin = 48.21178, xmax = 16.44011, ymax = 48.2380217752047), class = "bbox"), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"))), row.names = c(NA, 3L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(name = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"))
```

Now I want to create lines from each origin to all the destinations. That is 5 times 3 lines -> So in total 15 lines.

I guess I could split one of the dataframe and loop over the other and create the linestrings. But I thought there might be solution involving `expand.grid` and creating sf-linestrings from that. But I could not figure it out now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

See the reprex below.

```r
# packages
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.1, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

origin <- st_sf(
  data.frame(x = 1:5), 
  geometry = st_geometry(
    st_sfc(
      st_point(c(0, 0)), 
      st_point(c(0, 1)), 
      st_point(c(0, 2)), 
      st_point(c(0, 3)), 
      st_point(c(0, 4))
    )
  )
)

destination <- st_sf(
  data.frame(y = 1:3), 
  geometry = st_geometry(
    st_sfc(
      st_point(c(2, 1)), 
      st_point(c(2, 2)), 
      st_point(c(2, 3))
    )
  )
)

lines <- st_sfc(apply(
  X = expand.grid(st_geometry(origin), st_geometry(destination)), 
  MARGIN = 1L, 
  FUN = function(x) {
    st_linestring(rbind(x[[1]], x[[2]]))
  }, 
  simplify = FALSE
))

# plot
plot(st_geometry(origin), reset = FALSE, xlim = c(-1, 3))
plot(st_geometry(destination), add = TRUE)
plot(lines, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>